# I have a problem with animating an svg picture

Tags: html, css, svg

I've created 2 svg pictures and wanted to animate them.
One of the pictures handle animation as i wanted, but the other one is makeing 2 lines instead of one filled with color. I wonder if its a problem with the svg file or i''ve made a mistake with the code.
Here is the code of the first one

```css
#svg_1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1400;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
    animation: two 5s ease-in forwards;
}

#svg_2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1400;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
    animation: two 5s ease-in forwards;
}

#svg_4 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1400;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
    animation: two 5s ease-in forwards;
}


#svg_5 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1400;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
    animation: two 5s ease-in forwards;
}



@keyframes two {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
    }

    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">                
                <g>
                    <title>background</title>
                    <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="602" width="802" y="-1" x="-1" />
                    <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                        <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" />
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <title>Layer 1</title>
                    <rect id="svg_1" height="446" width="252" y="104.45313" x="122.5" stroke-width="14" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
                    <line stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="467.45313" x2="378.5" y1="465.45313" x1="120.5" stroke-width="14" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
                    <ellipse ry="23" rx="45" id="svg_3" cy="507.45313" cx="249.5" stroke-width="14" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
                    <line stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_4" y2="164.45313" x2="375.5" y1="162.45313" x1="123.5" stroke-width="14" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
                    <rect id="svg_5" height="24" width="131" y="120.45313" x="185.5" stroke-width="14" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
                </g>
            </svg>
```

And here is the code of another one which does not work properly

```css
@keyframes help {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }

    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

#layer1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: help 5s ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
            <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                 xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
                 xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
                 sodipodi:docname="cobysiemusialostac.svg"
                 inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)"
                 id="svg8"
                 version="1.1"
                 viewBox="0 0 210 297"
                 height="297mm"
                 width="210mm">
                <defs id="defs2" />
                <sodipodi:namedview inkscape:window-maximized="0"
                                    inkscape:window-y="0"
                                    inkscape:window-x="52"
                                    inkscape:window-height="1040"
                                    inkscape:window-width="1465"
                                    showgrid="false"
                                    inkscape:document-rotation="0"
                                    inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
                                    inkscape:document-units="mm"
                                    inkscape:cy="560"
                                    inkscape:cx="400"
                                    inkscape:zoom="0.35"
                                    inkscape:pageshadow="2"
                                    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
                                    borderopacity="1.0"
                                    bordercolor="#666666"
                                    pagecolor="#ffffff"
                                    id="base" />
                <metadata id="metadata5">
                    <rdf:RDF>
                        <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                            <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                            <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                            <dc:title></dc:title>
                        </cc:Work>
                    </rdf:RDF>
                </metadata>
                <g id="layer1"
                   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
                   inkscape:label="Warstwa 1">
                    <path id="path32"
                          d="m 32.49157,256.7856 c -2.12058,-1.09824 -4.13468,-3.83205 -4.56547,-6.1969 l -0.29143,-1.59978 17.3698,-100.48131 17.36981,-100.481298 0.81955,-1.42243 c 1.23874,-2.149973 4.01205,-3.995888 6.48242,-4.314701 1.84853,-0.238561 1.91572,-0.227646 53.28698,8.655523 l 51.43612,8.894385 1.67753,0.853823 c 1.41676,0.72109 1.88351,1.146169 3.00245,2.734393 0.9624,1.366022 1.40761,2.319178 1.62715,3.483589 l 0.30224,1.603018 -17.37078,100.481118 -17.37079,100.48112 -0.82938,1.41938 c -0.6048,1.03504 -1.33829,1.77855 -2.70885,2.74584 -1.5873,1.12026 -2.16969,1.36392 -3.74632,1.56739 l -1.86685,0.24092 -51.52623,-8.92505 c -50.94694,-8.8247 -51.5439,-8.93419 -53.09795,-9.73903 z m 106.28907,17.15439 c 1.90635,-0.2709 4.32979,-1.82085 5.46454,-3.49493 l 0.85857,-1.26662 2.38314,-13.30452 2.38315,-13.30452 -37.72332,-6.70182 c -20.74782,-3.68601 -46.9691,-8.30066 -58.2695,-10.25479 l -20.54619,-3.55297 -2.2529,13.50581 -2.25289,13.50582 0.38337,1.48137 c 0.49403,1.90892 2.35773,4.35349 3.92603,5.14966 0.98825,0.5017 8.60478,1.87738 52.67843,9.51464 47.74692,8.27379 51.629,8.91308 52.96757,8.72287 z M 83.23549,262.49356 c -4.60477,-1.9963 -8.08616,-6.90268 -8.35566,-11.77576 -0.0862,-1.55895 0.51986,-5.06387 1.12457,-6.50335 0.89886,-2.13969 2.58919,-4.17999 4.69776,-5.67037 6.44946,-4.5586 14.85552,-3.09489 19.33424,3.36658 2.20954,3.18772 2.90046,6.34735 2.22911,10.19379 -0.69439,3.97836 -2.35547,6.63988 -5.52486,8.85241 -4.15139,2.89806 -9.07316,3.45808 -13.50516,1.53669 z m 6.35597,-0.22702 c 9.99704,-0.83748 15.09385,-12.16137 9.0628,-20.13538 -6.5518,-8.66253 -20.37167,-5.24025 -22.22972,5.50485 -1.39222,8.05117 5.13454,15.30343 13.16692,14.63053 z M 164.03369,160.48319 177.98687,79.792162 119.71726,69.716122 61.44764,59.640083 47.51722,140.19955 33.5868,220.75902 l 27.29811,4.79003 c 15.01397,2.63452 41.22506,7.22794 58.24687,10.2076 l 30.94874,5.41757 z M 179.0283,73.460882 c 0.90221,-6.027029 0.78101,-7.01602 -1.16823,-9.532242 -2.09392,-2.702984 2.84042,-1.657401 -55.12226,-11.680365 C 64.77514,42.22531 69.77406,42.897398 66.89407,44.740288 c -2.681,1.715557 -3.12728,2.606418 -4.30134,8.586438 l -0.98147,4.999099 58.33141,10.086726 58.33141,10.086727 z M 97.87737,58.904587 c -0.1671,-0.236967 -0.0975,-1.299734 0.19658,-3.000169 0.29404,-1.700436 0.58533,-2.724874 0.8223,-2.891971 0.53198,-0.37513 48.01341,7.835406 48.38854,8.367396 0.1671,0.236968 0.0975,1.299734 -0.19658,3.00017 -0.29404,1.700435 -0.58533,2.724874 -0.82229,2.89197 -0.53199,0.37513 -48.01342,-7.835406 -48.38855,-8.367396 z m 48.16798,5.295094 0.33813,-1.955356 -23.46428,-4.057466 -23.46427,-4.057466 -0.33812,1.955357 -0.33812,1.955356 23.46427,4.057465 23.46427,4.057466 z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
```

Comment: The second SVG is the problem. It seems to be the result of someone using Inkscape to edit it, and having used its "Stroke to Path" conversion command so that it, if you set `fill:black;stroke:none`, would still looks like lines, but actually are now filled areas. Unfortunately, this is a destructive operation that cannot be reverted. You need the SVG file version before that conversion took place.